# Blazor Server-side Restart the app @onclick event

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor Forms Calculator that takes inputs and calculates numbers. At the end I have two buttons, Download PDF (with the results) and New Calculation that will restart the application.

```
<button @onclick=Print style="background-color:green;">
    Download PDF
</button>
<button  style="background-color:green;">
    New Calculation
</button>
```

Can I do that with the @onclick event or call a Javascript function?

Comment: Do you want to restart the "application" or just reset the calculator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Navigation Manager and have navigated the app on the Index page

```
    private void HandleClick()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
}
```

calling it on click

```
    <button @onclick=HandleClick style="background-color:green;" class="btn btn- 
        primary btn-medium hidewhenprint">
     New Calculation
        </button>
```

Comment: There is no need to restart application  or reload page to achieve the functionality you want,  just reset you calculator to initial values